# Calculation for Percentage of total (per row) giving #Error

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, percentage

I am using SSRS 2008r2.  I need to add a column for the percentage of total which seems straightforward however I have been struggling with this for a week and have read numerous posts on percentage problems and have not found anything that works.

**Basically my query is which is the best way to do this - in the report body or in the SQL code? and then can anyone help with how to get that to work.**

What I have done so far:

[image: Image of SSRS layout]
In SSRS I added an expression into the end column to divide the count of records per type by the value in the total row:
=Fields!WebCommsPrefContact.Value/ReportItems!WebCommsPrefContact1
and I formatted the expression cell to percentage format in 'Text Box Properties'.  However the results show an Error.  I have read a lot of posts about this but they all seem to refer to dividing by zero but the total row will never contain a zero.
[image: Results from ReportItems use]

I then thought that maybe I need to add the percentage as a column into my SQL code:
The original code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cp.tsg_communicationpreferencetypeidname AS WebCommsPrefType, con.tsg_contactuid AS WebCommsPrefContact
FROM            Filteredccx_communicationpreference AS cp INNER JOIN
                         FilteredContact AS con ON cp.ccx_contact = con.contactid INNER JOIN
                         FilteredAccount AS comp ON con.accountid = comp.accountid
WHERE        (cp.ccx_informationsource = 803080004) AND (con.statecode = 0) AND (cp.createdon BETWEEN '2016/11/25' AND '2017/10/13') AND (NOT EXISTS
                             (SELECT        tsg_companyuid
                               FROM            FilteredAccount
                               WHERE        (comp.tsg_companyuid IN ('COMP00153968', 'COMP00091748', 'COMP00177586', 'COMP00231427', 'COMP00077428', 'COMP00077490', 'COMP00255796')))) AND 
                         (cp.tsg_communicationpreferencecategoryidname LIKE 'Category 4%') AND (cp.ccx_status = 803080000)
ORDER BY WebCommsPrefType
```

I tried to add a new column by adding a new subquery into the select row but that resulted in all zeros: (in this extract I am still trying to get the total number of rows so have not yet added in the division part to get the percentage result) - The syntax is obviously not correct

```
SELECT DISTINCT cp.tsg_communicationpreferencetypeidname AS WebCommsPrefType, con.tsg_contactuid AS WebCommsPrefContact, 
count(select Filteredccx_communicationpreference.tsg_communicationpreferencetypeidname AS WebCommsPrefType, FilteredContact.tsg_contactuid AS WebCommsPrefContact
                        FROM            Filteredccx_communicationpreference  INNER JOIN
                                                 FilteredContact ON   Filteredccx_communicationpreference.ccx_contact = FilteredContact.contactid INNER JOIN
                                                 FilteredAccount  ON  FilteredContact.accountid = FilteredAccount.accountid
                        WHERE        (  Filteredccx_communicationpreference.ccx_informationsource = 803080004) AND ( FilteredContact.statecode = 0) AND (Filteredccx_communicationpreference.createdon BETWEEN '2016/11/25' AND '2017/10/13') AND (NOT EXISTS
                                                     (SELECT        tsg_companyuid
                                                       FROM            FilteredAccount
                                                       WHERE        (FilteredAccount.tsg_companyuid IN ('COMP00153968', 'COMP00091748', 'COMP00177586', 'COMP00231427', 'COMP00077428', 'COMP00077490', 'COMP00255796')))) AND 
                                                 (  Filteredccx_communicationpreference.tsg_communicationpreferencecategoryidname LIKE 'Category 4%') AND (Filteredccx_communicationpreference.ccx_status = 803080000)) as RecordCount


From 
                    Filteredccx_communicationpreference AS cp INNER JOIN
                        FilteredContact AS con ON cp.ccx_contact = con.contactid INNER JOIN
                        FilteredAccount AS comp ON con.accountid = comp.accountid
WHERE        (cp.ccx_informationsource = 803080004) AND (con.statecode = 0) AND (cp.createdon BETWEEN '2016/11/25' AND '2017/10/13') AND (NOT EXISTS
                            (SELECT        tsg_companyuid
                            FROM            FilteredAccount
                            WHERE        (comp.tsg_companyuid IN ('COMP00153968', 'COMP00091748', 'COMP00177586', 'COMP00231427', 'COMP00077428', 'COMP00077490', 'COMP00255796')))) AND 
                        (cp.tsg_communicationpreferencecategoryidname LIKE 'Category 4%') AND (cp.ccx_status = 803080000)
```

I then thought that maybe I need to add an inner join to a table resulting in the total row count.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cp.tsg_communicationpreferencetypeidname AS WebCommsPrefType, count(con.tsg_contactuid) AS WebCommsPrefContact, count(con.tsg_contactuid)/count(X.PContact) as percentage
FROM            Filteredccx_communicationpreference AS cp INNER JOIN
                         FilteredContact AS con ON cp.ccx_contact = con.contactid INNER JOIN
                         FilteredAccount AS comp ON con.accountid = comp.accountid Inner join
                         (select Distinct Filteredccx_communicationpreference.tsg_communicationpreferencetypeidname AS WebCommsPrefType, FilteredContact.tsg_contactuid as PContact
                         FROM            Filteredccx_communicationpreference  INNER JOIN
                         FilteredContact  ON Filteredccx_communicationpreference.ccx_contact = FilteredContact .contactid INNER JOIN
                         FilteredAccount ON FilteredContact.accountid = FilteredAccount.accountid
                            WHERE        (Filteredccx_communicationpreference.ccx_informationsource = 803080004) AND (FilteredContact.statecode = 0) AND (Filteredccx_communicationpreference.createdon BETWEEN '2016/11/25' AND '2017/10/16') AND (NOT EXISTS
                             (SELECT        tsg_companyuid
                               FROM            FilteredAccount
                               WHERE        (FilteredAccount.tsg_companyuid IN ('COMP00153968', 'COMP00091748', 'COMP00177586', 'COMP00231427', 'COMP00077428', 'COMP00077490', 'COMP00255796')))) AND 
                         (Filteredccx_communicationpreference.tsg_communicationpreferencecategoryidname LIKE 'Category 4%') AND (Filteredccx_communicationpreference.ccx_status = 803080000)) as X ON cp.ccx_contact=X.PContact

WHERE        (cp.ccx_informationsource = 803080004) AND (con.statecode = 0) AND (cp.createdon BETWEEN '2016/11/25' AND '2017/10/16') AND (NOT EXISTS
                             (SELECT        tsg_companyuid
                               FROM            FilteredAccount
                               WHERE        (comp.tsg_companyuid IN ('COMP00153968', 'COMP00091748', 'COMP00177586', 'COMP00231427', 'COMP00077428', 'COMP00077490', 'COMP00255796')))) AND 
                         (cp.tsg_communicationpreferencecategoryidname LIKE 'Category 4%') AND (cp.ccx_status = 803080000)
                         Group By  cp.tsg_communicationpreferencetypeidname
ORDER BY WebCommsPrefType
```

But this only returns the headers with no results.  I think that this maybe the link between the main tables and the sub-query table but I am struggling to see how to get the count exactly the same as in the outer query without having the exact same code as each contact can have multiple types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took another look at my question this morning when I wasn't so tired and the answer is so simple.  I am missing the .value part of the expression and did not need to go down the route of trying to find the perfect answer within my SQL code.  The simple and easy answer is to do the percentage calculation in the body of the report in SSRS using the expression:

```
=Fields!WebCommsPrefContact.Value/ReportItems!WebCommsPrefContact1.Value
```

and then format the text box to percentage.